# FormRequest returns no results despite the form looking correctly filled out in the response

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, http-post

I'm trying to scrape opening hours from Halifax bank branches on their official branch finder website (https://www.halifax.co.uk/branchfinder/search.asp) but I must be doing something wrong in the FormRequest.from_response() call, because the response to the FormRequest seems to be unchanged from the original response.

Passing in the 'postcode' value 'EH', there should be a single result (Edinburgh, 131 Princes Street, EH2 4AH), as seen when you do the same thing on the website, but I'm not getting anything when I do it using a FormRequest

This is the relevant part of the site's source:

```
<form action="" id="branch-finder-search-form" method="post">
    <div style="display:none;" class="notice error" aria-live="assertive"></div>
    <div class="field split-2 clearfix">
        <div class="split radio">
            <div class="field-radio">
                <input value="branch" name="searchType" checked id="r1" type="radio"><label for="r1"><span></span>Branch</label>
            </div>
            <div class="field-radio">
                <input value="cash" name="searchType" id="r2" type="radio"><label for="r2"><span></span>Cash Machine</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field split-3 clearfix">
        <div class="split">
            <label for="street">Street</label><input name="street" id="street" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="split">
            <label for="town">Town</label><input name="town" id="town" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="split last">
            <label for="postcode">Post Code</label><input name="postcode" id="postcode" type="text" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field clearfix">
        <div class="split btn-submit">
            <input id="search" name="search" alt="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="button button-primary" title="search"><span class="a_hide">ext search</span></input>
        </div>
        <noscript>
            <input value="yes" name="javascriptoff" id="javascriptoff" type="hidden">
            <div class="split btn-submit-nonjs">
                <input name="nonjsSubmit" type="submit" alt="Search" value="Search" class="button button-primary" title="search"><span class="a_hide">ext search</span></input>
            </div>
            <div></div>
        </noscript>
        <div style="display:none" id="no-result">
            <p>No Branch Found as per your search criteria</p>
        </div>
        <div id="branch-finder-results-container">
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is my code so far:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.response import open_in_browser
from scrapy.http import FormRequest
import scrapy


class HalifaxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "halifax"
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.halifax.co.uk/branchfinder/search.asp"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.text)
        yield FormRequest.from_response(response, formname='branch-finder-search-form', formdata={"postcode": "EH"}, callback=self.open_in_browser)

    def open_in_browser(self, response):
        print(response.text)
        open_in_browser(response)


crawler = CrawlerProcess()
crawler.crawl(HalifaxSpider)
crawler.start()
```

I've also tried passing in the argument clickdata={"name": "search"}, in case the search button isn't being clicked, but I get the same result.

I'm really new to web scraping in general, so I'm just really stuck and don't know where to go from here. I've read some of the documentation, but there isn't much information or tutorials on filling out all sorts of different kinds of forms, so I'm at a loss.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following approach to fetch the required data. Headers plays an important role here, so make sure you include that (I've already added that).

```
import scrapy
import urllib
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class HalifaxSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "halifax"
    url = "https://www.halifax.co.uk/asp_includes/branch-finder/branch-finder.asp?"

    def start_requests(self):
        formdata = {
            'street': '',
            'town': '',
            'postcode': 'EH',
            'searchType': 'branch'
        }
        req_url = f'{self.url}{urllib.parse.urlencode(formdata)}'
        yield scrapy.Request(req_url,callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self,response):
        print(response.css("h2#resultTitle1 ::text").getall())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    crawler = CrawlerProcess({'USER_AGENT':'Mozilla/5.0'})
    crawler.crawl(HalifaxSpider)
    crawler.start()
```

Comment: Did you try the script @MatthewGdV?